# Bet calculator not working when using negative money line

Tags: javascript

Good day all,

I am trying to create a simple small bet calculator with the following line of codes:

```
function betCalculator(moneyLine) {
    var odds;
    var betAmount = 500;    
if (moneyLine > 0) {
    odds = (moneyLine / 100) + 1;

} else {
    odds = (100 / moneyLine) + 1;

}
return parseFloat((odds * betAmount).toFixed(2));
}
console.log(betCalculator(130)); // Result / Expected = 1150.00
```

But if I change the Money Line to negative, say -130, as shown below:

```
function betCalculator(moneyLine) {
    var odds;
    var betAmount = 500;    
if (moneyLine > 0) {
    odds = (moneyLine / 100) + 1;

} else {
    odds = (100 / moneyLine) + 1;

}
return parseFloat((odds * betAmount).toFixed(2));
}
console.log(betCalculator(-130)); // Result I am getting = 115.38 // Expected = 884.62
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
if (moneyLine > 0) {
    odds = (moneyLine / 100) + 1;
```

But

```
if (moneyLine < 0) {    
     odds = (100 / moneyLine) + 1;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
ZeManel

Comment: `Expected = 884.62` why? what is the maths behind that? `((100 / (-130)) + 1) * 500` is definitely `115.38415....`

Comment: your code should be `odds = (-100 / moneyLine) + 1;` in the else case

Comment: Hello Jaromanda. You are right. I was missing the Math.abs as mentioned by Willman. In excel I use "IF(B3>0,(B3/100)+1,(100/ABS(B3))+1)" for either positive or negative money line and it works just fine. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes. Having it odds = (-100 / moneyLine) + 1; as per your suggestion, also works. I did not realize that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the calculation for the negative moneyLine, you want to change the sign, or use the absolute value, when you move it to the denominator.

If you change `odds = (100 / moneyLine) + 1;` in your else condition to `odds = (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1;`, then you will get your expected answer.

Comment: or simply `(100/moneyLine)` since `moneyLine` is guaranteed to be negative, dividing it into a negative will give the same result with 9 less keystrokes :D

Comment: Thanks Willman. That's exactly the way I wanted it to be.  Now if I can transform the IF(B3>0,(B3/100)+1,(100/ABS(B3))+1) excel formula into javascript and use it for both positive and/or negative money lines would be better. Sometimes, a bet ticket has both positive and negative money lines. I am just learning javascript. My desire is create a parlay calculator. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you are doing now in JavaScript is already effectively the equivalent of that formula. If you are looking for the value to be updated automatically as the user changes their moneyLine input, you can always trigger your betCalculator function on the onChange event of their input text box, then write your calculated value to some html element on the page.  This would allow the user to see the value in real time as they change their input.

Comment: Hello again,
The above excel formula ( IF(B3>0,(B3/100)+1,(100/ABS(B3))+1) ) is a combination of two in one if condition. It allows me to place positive or negative Money Lines to calculate the odds. 

eg. 'if (moneyLine > 0) {
    odds = (moneyLine / 100) + 1; '

or 'if (moneyLine < 0) {    
     odds = (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1; '

In javascript, is there any way I can place those two formulas in one line, just like in excel and get the same results?

Regards,
ZeManel

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment, if your goal is to get the value to change in real time like an Excel calculated cell, does, then you just need to trigger your code as the handler for the onChange event of the user's input box.  If you truly want to get it all on a single line of code, it doesn't really achieve anything more, but using the "?" and ":" conditional operators which are the equivalent of "if..then..else", you could write  `odds = moneyLine >= 0 ? (moneyLine / 100) + 1 : (100 / Math.abs(moneyLine)) + 1;`

Comment: also, if you using some form of "if..else" make sure you use ">=0" instead of just ">0", if the user enters a moneyLink of zero, you want to odds to come out to one, but if zero falls to your "else" condition, you will get a "divide by zero" exception.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206291/discussion-between-manny-and-willman).